# Can an element be added to an array conditionally with in-line syntax?

Tags: arrays, swift, conditional-statements

Given an array

```
let array: [Int]
```

and a variable

```
let addElement: Bool
```

Can an element be added conditionally only if `addElement` is true using an in-line syntax?

The following works:

```
let addElement = false
let array = [0, 1, addElement ? 2 : nil] //[0, 1, nil]
```

But there should be no element at all, not just a `nil` value.
Can that be written in-line like in the example above?

Comment: `let array = [ 0, 1 ] + (addElement ? [ 2 ] : [])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want this inline, you can use `compactMap` to remove the `nil` elements:

```
let addElement = false
let array = [0, 1, addElement ? 2 : nil].compactMap { $0 } //[0, 1]
```

This has the advantage that you can insert the optional element anywhere within the array:

```
let addElement = true
let array = [0, addElement ? 2 : nil, 1].compactMap { $0 } //[0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I guess that's the most "compact" answer with the current Swift syntax, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

While the following method does not define the element within the array's initialization, it does have the advantage of the new index not being pre-defined. 
I would assume that this is the closest you could get to an in-line solution.

```
let addElement: Bool = false
var array = [0, 1]
(addElement) ? array.append(2) : Void()
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the same as a separate if clause. I am looking explicitly for an in-line format. The `Void()` is redundant, `if (addElement) { ... }` would be even cleaner.